# Markov Transition Probability Matrix

Tags: python, r, statistics, transition, markov-chains

I am having trouble in calculating transition probability matrix. I have a couple of ids and their search pattern (page visited). Example:

```
Id  Page
1   A
1   A
1   B
2   C
2   C
3   D
3   E
3   F
1   D
1   G
4   G
4   C
4   H
2   D
2   C
```

I also have initial probabilities of the pages: P_a,...., P_h. How do I code in R (preferably) or Python to get the transition probability matrix for Page variable for all ids. I know how to do it for single id but cannot understand for multiple ids.

Comment: Please show us some code, and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way. Do you know what transition matrix is? You need to tell the computer states to states, for example, (1,A) **to** (2,C).

Your data doesn't have the information.